# SSIS - need help on processing data

Tags: oracle, ssis

I am new to SSIS.  I have been given a task to load data from flat files to Oracle Target table.  Some how i was able to do this.  But i have another requirement to check the flat file data for existence before inserting to the target.

Can you please throw some idea(s) which transformation to use?

Using SSIS 2008 (using with Attunity Oracle drivers)
Oracle 11g target

thanks in advance

Comment: Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you are new to SSIS, how about you read some examples and guides rather than asking here?

Comment: The term you will be looking to search on is "SSIS Incremental load"

Comment: Load the data in the Staging table from the staging table load data into the destination table using a SQL Merge script. [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) performing this task using a stored procedure will be much faster than using a Lookup transformation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the existence before inserting, **you need to use a LookUp transformation**. It will check a value inside the table and you have this 2 options:

- If it doesn´t, you can redirect not matching rows, and send the row to the destination table.
- **IF IT DOES EXIST**, you can either ignore it or save that row on a flat file.

LookUp Transformation also gives you the option to use the Cache Memory:

1. Full Cache: the database is queried and 'memorizes' the data BEFORE
   doing any transformation or insert into it.
2. Partial Cache: uses a partial cache, and if no match is found,
   queries the database.
3. No Cache: It does not maintain a Lookup cache, so it queries the
   database for every row proccessed.

You can find more detailed information about [LookUp Transformation here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/10/18/lookup-cache-modes/)

Hope it was what you were looking for

Comment: As bc004346 commented i guess i need to re write my question.